# Update a table automatically when a date is reached

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
id      int,
deadline    timestamp,
state       bool
```

When a record is inserted, I set state in true. This table will have a lot of records with different deadlines. When a deadline is reached by the current date I need to set state in false.

I thought of creating a process which should be executed once per second to update the table but in my opinion, it would be heavy (cron)

Another way would be with a trigger which will be executed each time this table being accessed.

Which is the best way to do it? Do you have any idea?

Please let me know how I can do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, you should be handling that with your PHP, and not in the database.  In other words, you should only check the record as it is called up, and change it f necessary.  But don't try updating the entire table.  That will kill your server.

Comment: The best way (imo) is to get rid of the flag. Struct your queries then in a way, that instead of `WHERE state = true` they compute the state themselfes. In this case, in order to retreive all rows after the deadline, select them via `WHERE deadline < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: Actually, the flag state will have more states I put true or false as an example. It could be Active, not active, pending, etc.